# Event handler for the new specific object appearence on squish using python?

Tags: python, event-handling, squish

Let's say I'd like to hit button contained in the new dialog just in time this dialog will appear.
How should my event handler look?

Example:

```
def handleMyNewDialogAppeared():
    mouseClick(waitForObject(":MyButtonOnNewDialog"), MouseButton.LeftButton)

def main():
    startApplication("myapp")
    installEventHandler("if dialog :MyNewDialog appeared", 
                        "handleMyNewDialogAppeared")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never user the eventHandler from Squish.
Instead of this (my problems is that all my objects are dynamic) I've created a custom wait function of mine. It works for all objects, no matter of their form/type.

This functions waits until an object is true.

```
def whileObjectFalse(objectID, log = True):
    # functions enters in a while state, as long as expected object is FALSE, exiting when object is TRUE 
    # (default timeout of [20s])

    start = time.time()# START timer
    counter = 40
    object_exists = object.exists(objectID)
    while object_exists == False:
        object_exists = object.exists(objectID)
        snooze(0.5)
        counter -= 1
        if counter == 0:
            test.fail(" >> ERR: in finding the object [%s]. Default timeout of [20s] reached!" % objectID)
            return
    if log == True:
        elapsed = (time.time() - start)# STOP timer
        test.log("    (whileObjectFalse(): waited [%s] after object [%s])" % (elapsed, objectID))
    snooze(0.5)
```

So basicaly, your code will be like this:

```
def whileObjectFalse(objectID, log = True):
        start = time.time()# START timer
        counter = 40
        object_exists = object.exists(objectID)
        while object_exists == False:
            object_exists = object.exists(objectID)
            snooze(0.5)
            counter -= 1
            if counter == 0:
                test.fail(" >> ERR: in finding the object [%s]. Default timeout of [20s] reached!" % objectID)
                return
        if log == True:
            elapsed = (time.time() - start)# STOP timer
            test.log("    (whileObjectFalse(): waited [%s] after object [%s])" % (elapsed, objectID))
        snooze(0.5)


def main():
    startApplication("myapp")
    whileObjectFalse("NewDialog")
    mouseClick(waitForObject(":MyButtonOnNewDialog"), MouseButton.LeftButton)
```

Comment: Your `waitObjectFalse` function could be simplified a lot by using `waitFor(lambda: object.exists(objectID))` -- the `waitFor` function takes care of the looping, you can use the return value to decide whether the object exists or not.

Comment: yes, you are right .. I will use this next time. I don't know why I didn't thought of that at the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific event named "DialogOpened" for that, however it hooks every dialog.
You can then check in the handler whether it is the dialog you need, like this:

```
def handleMyNewDialogAppeared(Dialog):
    if str(Dialog.windowTitle) == "My Dialog's Title":  # whatever suits your needs
        mouseClick(waitForObject(":MyButtonOnNewDialog"), MouseButton.LeftButton)

def main():
    startApplication("myapp")
    installEventHandler("DialogOpened", "handleMyNewDialogAppeared")
```

I, however, only have squish for Qt so I cannot verify this for windows.